# Static Image Asset Unable to Be Required (RN v0.14.1)

Tags: android, react-native

I was not able to require the static image, while the image is clearly imported into Android Studio under Res/drawable folder. I did run react-native run-android command line to compile the image but the framework returns "requiring unknown module "image!menu" "error. I have noticed previous discussion about similar errors on v0.3.0 but that seems to be for the iPhone platform and fix patched for that specific report. I've also tried restarting the JS server and updating Android Studio to latest. V0.14.0 returns the same error.

Previous discussion: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/282

My system info is Mac OS+RN0.14.1 (Android) + Genymotion. I've spent hours today on this bug as image is a crucial part of my app. Really appreciate your help！

Answer (score 0):

running command react-native start --assetRoots ./android/app/src/main/res/ under the project root directory solves the problem. Credits go to this post: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4033#issuecomment-155360225